# What exactly is a 生徒?

Tags: etymology, culture

The word 生徒(せいと) means "pupil", but what exactly is/was a 生徒 in Japanese culture? And how is a 生徒 different from a 学生? And in what context would you use the word?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11706/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my Japanese dictionary, 広辞林, the two words are defined as follows:

- 生徒　-- refers to a student receiving an education from a fixed location such as in middle or high school or from under a tutor etc.

  > 中高等大学校または家塾その他、一定の場所で教育を受ける人。
- 学生 -- refers to a someone who attends classes, but in particular someone who studies at university.

  > 学業をおさめるもの。特に、大学に学ぶ者。大学生。

From this it seems that 学生 is the more general term covering a wider range of students including those in the category of 生徒.  As @naruto pointed out in the comments, 学生 isn't quite as general as those definitions might leave one to think (now I'm a bit disappointed in my dictionary).  Apparently, 生徒 is the more appropriate terms for a student taking a culinary class, or swimming lessons, or studying martial arts, and I would therefor imagine a number of other things.

Comment: ありがとうございます！ *bows like a gaijin*

Comment: 学生 is not necessarily more generic because one can only use 生徒 in 料理教室の生徒 or スイミングスクールの生徒.

Comment: So... 生徒 is used for students in an education system that isn't part of the standardised education system and isn't something like martial arts where a different word is used? Is that it, more or less?

Comment: 生徒 is more common term for "student", regardless if it's educated in formal education system or other things outside it. But 学生 is more specifically termed to "school student", possibly shorthand for 学校生徒.

Comment: [You can safely use 生徒](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43906/5010) for schools of martial arts.

Comment: @naruto So would 生徒 then also be more appropriate for someone studying the tea ceremony and ikebana too?  Or even a nontraditional arts such as yoga?  I suppose that's what one might gather from 一定の場所で教育を受ける人, right?

Comment: Yes, where there's a 先生, there's a 生徒 :-)

Comment: It's prudent to think of a 学生 as a class of 生徒, that is, all 学生 are 生徒 but not all 生徒 are 学生. That's because a 学生 is a specific kind of 生徒 that is studying in a more specific manner, i.e. in a classroom, at a university, etc. but a 生徒 is a student, in general, regardless of location or subject. That's the way I've understood it.

Comment: @Yamamoto `possibly shorthand for 学校生徒` -- Naw, 学生 is NEVER short for 学校生徒. `学生 is more specifically termed to "school student"` -- Naw, we don't use 学生 for primary and middle school students.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that 学生 strongly implies that it is a pupil in a school, while 生徒 is simply a "pupil", someone who learns from someone.

There are many terms for students depending on the situation (school, martial arts, beginner, expert, etc.), but pupil really feels suitable for them all.

Answer (score 2):

In the Japanese school system, it depends on whether you go to elementary school, junior/high school, or university.

Kindergarten or daycare - 園児
Elementary school - 児童
Junior high or high school - 生徒
University - 学生

Source:

https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/gimon/143.html